# WPF Column Widths and a TextBlock Sizing

Tags: wpf, grid, textblock

I have a grid in xaml that has two columns with widths 4.5* and 5.5*

In column 1 i have a textblock. When this textblock has text that is very long it is making the textblock column very wide and my second column is getting smaller.

I need the textblock column to stay the wide that is set and wrap the text instead.

Here is the xaml:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="25"  />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="4.5*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="5.5*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock x:Name="lblCheck" Text="{Binding Path=Text}"  Grid.Column="0"  Grid.Row="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
    <CheckBox x:Name="chkOption" Grid.Column="1" IsChecked="{Binding Path=Checked}" Grid.Row="0"  IsEnabled="True"/>
</Grid>
```

Thanks

Comment: The code you are posting works just fine. If it isn't wrapping to the second row(rowheight limitation). Then the problem might be somewhere else. What is your Text property bound to? I'm guessing there is more to this window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted works fine, other than the fact your RowHeight is set to 35 so it only shows at most 2 lines of text for me.

Try setting your RowHeight to *

Answer (score 0):

What if you try to set width of column 1 as `4.5` and second as `*`